Using Rust's k256 crate, how to sign a message using ECDH's EphemeralSecret and ECDSA?
I am trying to implement the Ethereum handshake procedure (RLPx) at low level, as specified here:
https://github.com/ethereum/devp2p/blob/master/rlpx.md
I am using the k256 crate which provides facilities for working with ECDH and ECDSA.
I'd like to combine the two, but I haven't been able to.
The crate's ECDSA signing function, sign(), does not seem to support its ecdh::EphemeralSecret, which is required for the Diffie-Hellman key exchange procedure, so I need to work with it. It only seems to support ecdsa::SigningKey, but that is not supported by their ECDH, which only supports ecdh::EphemeralSecret.
ECDH documentation
ECDSA documentation
I have something like:
use ethereum_types::H256;
use hex;
use k256::{ecdh::EphemeralSecret, EncodedPoint, PublicKey, SecretKey};
use k256::ecdsa::{self, Signature, signature::Signer, SigningKey};
use k256::ecdsa::signature::SignerMut;
use rand_core::OsRng;
use rlp::RlpStream;
use secrecy::{ExposeSecret, Secret, Zeroize};

...

    let initiator_public_key = static_secret_key.public_key();
    let initiator_public_key = &(*(initiator_public_key.to_sec1_bytes()))[1..];

    let username = hex::decode(username)?;
    let mut aux = [0; 65];
    aux[0] = 4;
    aux[1..].copy_from_slice(username.as_ref());
    let recipient_public_key = PublicKey::from_sec1_bytes(aux.as_ref())?;

    let init_ephemeral_secret = EphemeralSecret::random(&mut OsRng);
    let init_ephemeral_secret = Secret::new(init_ephemeral_secret);

    let init_shared = init_ephemeral_secret
        .expose_secret()
        .diffie_hellman(&recipient_public_key);
    let init_shared = H256::from_slice(&init_shared.raw_secret_bytes()[..32]);

    let initiator_nonce = H256::random();

    // compute signature
    let message = init_shared ^ initiator_nonce;
    let signature: Signature = init_ephemeral_secret
        .expose_secret()
        .sign(message.as_fixed_bytes()); // ERROR

    // "auth_body" is an RLP stream of 4 values
    let mut rlp_stream = RlpStream::new_list(4);
    rlp_stream.append(&signature);
    rlp_stream.append(&initiator_public_key);
    rlp_stream.append(&initiator_nonce);
    rlp_stream.append(&5);
    let auth_body = rlp_stream.out();

...

username is the recipient's public key from its enode - the first part, before the IP address.
The error that I am getting is:
error[E0599]: the method `sign` exists for reference `&EphemeralSecret<Secp256k1>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied

113 |       let signature: Signature = init_ephemeral_secret
    |  ________________________________-
114 | |         .expose_secret()
115 | |         .sign(message.as_fixed_bytes());
    | |         -^^^^ method cannot be called on `&EphemeralSecret<Secp256k1>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
    | |_________|

93  |   pub struct EphemeralSecret<C>
    |   ----------------------------- doesn't satisfy `_: Signer<_>` or `_: SignerMut<_>`
    |
    = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `&k256::elliptic_curve::ecdh::EphemeralSecret<k256::Secp256k1>: k256::ecdsa::signature::Signer<_>`
            which is required by `&k256::elliptic_curve::ecdh::EphemeralSecret<k256::Secp256k1>: k256::ecdsa::signature::SignerMut<_>`
            `k256::elliptic_curve::ecdh::EphemeralSecret<k256::Secp256k1>: k256::ecdsa::signature::Signer<_>`
            which is required by `k256::elliptic_curve::ecdh::EphemeralSecret<k256::Secp256k1>: k256::ecdsa::signature::SignerMut<_>`


How can I make it work?

I'm curious about what protocol you're trying to implement that signs data using an ephemeral key. Can you give more details?

@PresidentJamesK.Polk I've linked the protocol at the beginning. It mentions ephemeral keys 10 times; could you search the page for ephemeral? It doesn't look nice if I put it here, but here's a little: ephemeral-key = ecdh.agree(ephemeral-privkey, remote-ephemeral-pubk);
shared-secret = keccak256(ephemeral-key || keccak256(nonce || initiator-nonce)). Also, the library works in that manner, but I can't get those two data (key) types to work interchangeably between ECDH and ECDSA.

I see only one mention of signing and that's about a hash over a public key. The ephemeral secret is a symmetric key; I think you are supposed to use a MAC. The whole term DSA is missing from the description.
